# Flash Change button color with ActionScript2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have Flash file with buttons in it, and the color of those buttons changes dynamically when flash loads, the color code is taken from XML file and it changes the color of button with

```
color.setRGB(color_code_from_xml);
```

And all here works ok. The problem is with hover color on those buttons, it should be always white but I just cant make it happen, after `setRGB()` loaded color all states of button (over, down, hit) is in that same color.

How to make the buttons keep the hover color white?

Hope this is understandable, I`m totally new to Flash. Thank you very much.

Comment: I recommend playing with MovieClip's [transform.colorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001686.html#538679). You're right, once you set a transform, it will be used until reset regardless of the frame/state of your MovieClip. You can either clear the color transform (by setting a new default one: `yourMC.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform()`) or change the tint to what colour you need by using altering the RGB components

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you, I`ll take a look at colorTransform it looks like to be the needed thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var color_code_from_xml:Number = 0xFF0000; // here you will pass your value from XML

var my_color:Color = new Color(my_button); 
my_color.setRGB(color_code_from_xml); // my_button turns to color (red) from XML

my_button.onRollOver = function() { // on mouse roll over
    my_color.setRGB(0xFFFFFF); // my_button turns white
}

my_button.onRollOut = function() { // on mouse roll out
    my_color.setRGB(color_code_from_xml);  // my_button restores to color (red) from XML
}

my_button.onPress = function() { // on mouse press
    my_color.setRGB(0x0066FF); // my_button turns blue
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the same as I figured out (forgot to post), and this worked. Thank you for your answer.